# Geodatabase Featureclass not editable in Python

Tags: arcpy, editing

I have a geodatabase featureclass that I need to add a field to. I can open this file in ArcMap and make all the edits I need, adding fields, calculating those fields, etc., but when I try to replicate the results in Python using the Add Field tool, I get this error message:

> ERROR 000499: table is not editable
>
> Failed to execute (AddField).

The file is stored in a file geodatabase, and I've made sure no other Arc programs are accessing it, so locks shouldn't be an issue as far as I can tell.

Why would I be able to edit the file in one program but not the other? How can I fix this?

It seems like it also works to bring up the python window within ArcMap/Catalog. The problem only exists when I use the Python Shell outside of Arc.

Comment: Are you checking out a license? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z0000000z000000

Comment: No, no licenses. None of the tools I'm using require any extensions.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a snippet of your code that isn't working